# Is there a standard term for a non-light-like interval expressed in mixed space and time components?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, terminology, education

One **might** call the representation of a time-like or space-like interval in its inertial rest frame a "proper" representation.  That is because the representation involves only dimensions in which its proper time or proper distance are measured.  That might lead one to call a mixed representation "improper", which is probably not a good term.  I don't like "mixed" either.  But it might work.

I might go for something like "proper" and "relative" to distinguish the two types of representation.  Is there an existing vocabulary to concisely make this distinction?

Here is an example of how this distinction can be used.  It is typical (for good reason) in discussions of SR to juxtapose *time dilation* with *length contraction*.  But that obscures an essential symmetry of spacetime.  It is exactly analogous(sic) to discussing trigonometry using $\tan, \cos$ and $\sec.$

In the following, the term *oblique* is used for intervals which have mixed space and time representations in the specific reference frame.  I use the term *proper* for those representations which have only time components or only space components.  $\mathcal{O}_3$ means 3-space origin.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is it that you would call the inertial rest frame of a spacelike interval?

Comment: A purely spacelike interval would also be called *proper*.  See the example I added to my question.  Note well that the proper length of an object being measured, and the proper interval of measurement are not necessarily the same thing.  See the *length contraction* section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "relative" refers to a component of a 4-vector.
(Note "proper" is derived from "property" [ownership], not "correctness".)

Often, an inertial observer's measurement of a spacetime displacement
is decomposed into a temporal-part and a spatial-part.

So, an observer measuring a timelike-displacement to have a zero spatial part
would consider that displacement to be "[purely]-temporal",
and similarly for "[purely]-spatial.

Allowing there to be [in your terms] "mixed" components for the 4-vectors
pointing into certain directions with respect to the light cone
is why Minkowski developed the notions of "timelike" and "spacelike".

If you are trying to specifically exclude the "pure-temporal" case from "timelike",
I am not aware of any standard term for that.

Would such a term be the spacetime analogue of "skew" or "slanted"?

---

From our discussion in the comments,
"oblique" could also be a possible term.

"Sloped" would be another possible term.

Comment: Oblique representation?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton "Oblique" seems appropriate. However, I don't think any of these terms ("skew", "slanted", and "oblique") are "standard terms" in spacetime geometry.

Comment: See the example added to my question in order to understand why I want terms that apply equally to spacelike and timelike intervals.  If you add the term *oblique* to the list of viable candidates, I will be happy to accept your answer since it is otherwise comprehensive.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I added "oblique" and "sloped".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only really describe it as a relationship between a vector and a basis.

If in some orthonormal basis in Minkowski space a spacelike vector is linearly dependent with the spacelike basis vectors, then the timelike component will be zero. Similiarly if a timelike vector is linearly dependent with the timelike basis vector then its spatial components will be zero.